# Duplicate element from for loop in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Given the code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("https://www.wellstar.org/locations/pages/wellstar-acworth-practices.aspx")
for table in soup.findAll("table", class_ = "s4-wpTopTable"):
    for specialty in table.findAll("div", class_ = "PurpleBackgroundHeading"):
        specialty = specialty.get_text(strip = True)
for name in table.findAll(class_ = "WS_Location_Name"):
    name = name.get_text()
    print(specialty, " - ", name)
```

This code yields the properly looped location name coupled with the improperly looped specialty name.  For example, the previous code produces:

```
Urology - Center for Spine Interventions, PC
Urology - WellStar Medical GroupCardiovascular Medicine
```

With `Urology - Georgia Urology` being the last couple produced.  How can I be sure to create pairs of Specialties and Location Names that correspond to reality?

Answer (score -1):

could it be the indentation?
How should the for loops be nested?
in python I would expect something like:

```
for tabele ...:
    for specialty ...:
        spe..
    for name ...:
        name ...
        print ...
```

or

```
for tabele ...:
    for specialty ...:
        spe..
        for name ...:
            name ...
            print ...
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, my code mimics the first example you have given.  I do get different results based on the indentation of the `print` command.  If one level of indentation is removed, I get the last pair possible `Urology - Georgia Urology` but I lose all previous iterations.